# glossaries: align top acronyms in multicols

Tags: glossaries, multicol, acronyms

I'm printing acronyms with `mcolalttree` but it outputs a blank space for default in the first column.How to remove this rectangle and add space below title ?

[image]

This is the code

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Acronyms

\newacronym{onu}{ONU}{Organización de las Naciones Unidas}
\newacronym{pnud}{PNUD}{Programa de las Naciones Unidas para el Desarrollo}
\newacronym{ods}{ODS}{Objetivos de Desarrollo sostenible}
\newacronym{pidesc}{PIDESC}{Pacto Internacional de Derechos Económicos, Sociales y Culturales}
\newacronym{wri}{WRI}{World Resources Institute}
\newacronym{gei}{GEI}{gases de efecto invernadero}
\newacronym{nrel}{NREL}{\textit{National Renewable Energy Laboratory}}
\newacronym{wqa}{WQA}{\textit{Water Quality Association}}
\newacronym{tsd}{TSD}{total de sólidos disueltos}
%Tecnologías de desalación
%Thermal
\newacronym{med}{MED}{Multi-Effect Distillation}
\newacronym{medad}{MEDAD}{Multi-Effect Distillation and Adsorption Desalination}
\newacronym{msf}{MSF}{Multistage Flash Distillation}
\newacronym{mvc}{MVC}{Mechanical Compression Distillation}
\newacronym{hdh}{HDH}{Humidification - Dehumification desalination}
\newacronym{sd}{SD}{Solar Distillation}
\newacronym{frz}{Frz}{Freezing}
%Pressure
\newacronym{ro}{RO}{Reverse Osmosis}
\newacronym{fo}{FO}{Forward Osmosis}
\newacronym{ed}{ED}{Electro Dyalysis}
\newacronym{nf}{NF}{Nanofiltration}
%Chemical
\newacronym{iex}{I.Ex}{Ion-Exchange desalination}
\newacronym{lle}{LLE}{Liquid-Liquid Extraction}
\newacronym{ghyd}{G. Hyd}{Gas Hydrate}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]

\begin{document}

    \glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\acronymtype]
    \printglossary[style=mcolalttree, type=\acronymtype, title=Abreviaciones y acrónimos, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this has some side effect.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{mymcolalttree}{% define custom glossaries style base on mcolalttree
\setglossarystyle{mcolalttree}%
\renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Acronyms

\newacronym{onu}{ONU}{Organización de las Naciones Unidas}
\newacronym{pnud}{PNUD}{Programa de las Naciones Unidas para el Desarrollo}
\newacronym{ods}{ODS}{Objetivos de Desarrollo sostenible}
\newacronym{pidesc}{PIDESC}{Pacto Internacional de Derechos Económicos, Sociales y Culturales}
\newacronym{wri}{WRI}{World Resources Institute}
\newacronym{gei}{GEI}{gases de efecto invernadero}
\newacronym{nrel}{NREL}{\textit{National Renewable Energy Laboratory}}
\newacronym{wqa}{WQA}{\textit{Water Quality Association}}
\newacronym{tsd}{TSD}{total de sólidos disueltos}
%Tecnologías de desalación
%Thermal
\newacronym{med}{MED}{Multi-Effect Distillation}
\newacronym{medad}{MEDAD}{Multi-Effect Distillation and Adsorption Desalination}
\newacronym{msf}{MSF}{Multistage Flash Distillation}
\newacronym{mvc}{MVC}{Mechanical Compression Distillation}
\newacronym{hdh}{HDH}{Humidification - Dehumification desalination}
\newacronym{sd}{SD}{Solar Distillation}
\newacronym{frz}{Frz}{Freezing}
%Pressure
\newacronym{ro}{RO}{Reverse Osmosis}
\newacronym{fo}{FO}{Forward Osmosis}
\newacronym{ed}{ED}{Electro Dyalysis}
\newacronym{nf}{NF}{Nanofiltration}
%Chemical
\newacronym{iex}{I.Ex}{Ion-Exchange desalination}
\newacronym{lle}{LLE}{Liquid-Liquid Extraction}
\newacronym{ghyd}{G. Hyd}{Gas Hydrate}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]

\begin{document}

    \glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\acronymtype]
    \printglossary[style=mymcolalttree, type=\acronymtype, title=Abreviaciones y acrónimos, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the only suggestion is to also subtract the parskip `\vspace{\dimexpr -\baselineskip -\parskip}`